# images left and right of text with figcaption

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

My page is paragraphs of text with a couple of pictures here and there.

I am able to put in the images fine, but making sure one aligns to right of paragraph, and further down the page another aligns to left of paragraph is beyond me.

It seems all the pictures on the page like to use the same code.

I looked into putting defining the figures with class but that did not work.

I have now defined them with id and that worked, but now the figcaptions are no longer aligned under the image.

Any help to understand what I'm doing wrong, or any easier way of getting what I want.

I need one image to align right of paragraph, with a figcaption under it and a different image elsewhere on the page to align left of paragraph with a figcaption under it.

```css
figure img#selfie {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

img.scaled {
  width: 100%;
}

figure img#yuri {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<figure>

  <p>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia19142_malhi-mojave.jpg">
      <img class="scaled" id="selfie" src="https://15809-presscdn-0-93-pagely.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/MTIyODA4OTg4OTIzNjI2MDg2.jpg" alt="Opportunity Rover takes a selfie on Mars">
    </a>
    <figcaption>
      The Opportunity rover takes the best selfies in the (known) universe.
    </figcaption>
</figure>



<figure>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia19142_malhi-mojave.jpg">
      <img class="scaled" id="yuri" src="http://pixiebooks.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/YuriG.jpg" alt="Yuri Gagarin">
    </a>
    <figcaption>
      Yuri Gagarin, the first man to orbit the Earth.
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to float the whole container i.e. `figure`

Remove the float from the image and add two new classes `right` and `left` which will `float: right` and `float: left` give the class to `<figure>`, now this should work:

```css
figure.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding: 0;
}

img.scaled {
  width: 100%;
}

figure.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure class="right">

  <p>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia19142_malhi-mojave.jpg">
      <img class="scaled" id="selfie" src="https://15809-presscdn-0-93-pagely.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/MTIyODA4OTg4OTIzNjI2MDg2.jpg" alt="Opportunity Rover takes a selfie on Mars">
    </a>
    <figcaption>
      The Opportunity rover takes the best selfies in the (known) universe.
    </figcaption>
</figure>



<figure class="left">
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia19142_malhi-mojave.jpg">
      <img class="scaled" id="yuri" src="http://pixiebooks.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/YuriG.jpg" alt="Yuri Gagarin">
    </a>
    <figcaption>
      Yuri Gagarin, the first man to orbit the Earth.
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: That's how I understood the problem as well, but the OP was muddling the issue by saying the page was mostly text, and then showing only the figures in the code.

Comment: _My page is paragraphs of text with a couple of pictures here and there._ he mentioned that there is images, but maybe he was not able to describe his issue accurately.

Comment: thank you so much, it was doing my head in. sorry for not describing properly. i am very new to html/css and have never asked for help before, so don't know the language...